# App installation failed on Release for device

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

The following error occurs:

> App installation failed: A valid provisioning profile for this
>   executable was not found

This only happens when i am trying to run the app on my device. When running on a simulator it all works fine. Im using the same provisioning profile in both cases.

Switching from `release` to `debug` works fine and installs both on a device and the simulator. What im trying to do is test the `release` version on the device.

Any clues? I've cleaned the project and all but since it installs fine on the simulator i imagine the error must come from somewhere else and not Xcode bugging out.

Thanks a bunch

Comment: You'll need to upload to the app store and test on your device using TestFlight.

Comment: Is this because its not allowed to run a release version on a device? I am essentially working with a react native app and want to test device performance without having to go through that process if thats possible as iteration is key here.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of the technical reasons, but the app store resigns the app which I think is what's required for the device.  One option is to create an ad hoc build but that requires that you copy the device id to the dev admin panel and create a new provisioning file.  Testflight is probably the easiest after Xcode debug... And FWIW,  there's rarely much difference between debug on device and TestFlight builds.

Comment: Unfortunately in this case there is as release mode strips a lot of debugging features that react native comes with and is very different from debug mode. Im still only using the development provisioning profile though and not the release one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use the `release provisioning-profile` on debug mode( debug mode refers to attach iOS device to your system via cable and run the project).

**To test the app for release mode:**

1. You need to archive the app
2. Upload the `.ipa` file on any of build sharing platform( such as diawi.com, testfairy.com)
3. Download from provided link.

---

**Enterprise Apple Account**:

If you are using **Enterprise Apple Account**, use `InHouse` option while creating provisiong-profile.

---

**iTunes Apple Account**:

If you are using **iTunes Apple Account**, use `AdHoc`(`AppStore` mode only works for apps which we will upload on App-Store) option while creating provisiong-profile.

You need to add device UDID in your developer account `Devices` section if you are wishing with `AdHoc` profile.

These are the steps to test iOS build on release mode.

Comment: But im not using the release provisioning profile in debug mode:/. Im using the development provisioning profile on release mode.

This works fine on the simulator but not on the device. The reason i need it is because in my case, React Native removes all debugging features from the app ( such as debugging popups and such ) .

Comment: @GeorgeAvgoustis, simulators are not real device. You can not use development provisioning profile on release mode for real devices. Even you can run your app without team or any provisioning-profile on simulator but on not real devices.